# Alter Large Block of Records with Data Macro

Tags: ms-access

Several hundred records were incorrectly entered into a table in my Access Database.

A particular ID number includes a two digit leading code that designates the state that record is from; so 01-24586 is a record from the ACT, and 02-55719 is a record from NSW. The incorrect entries have these two switched. I need to replace the first two digits of these records' IDs with the correct code.

To do this, I've tried to write a Named Data Macro that I can call from a regular macro object (so I can double click it in the navigation pane). I've done that, but it doesn't seem to work. My Data Macro (just one of the State fixes) looks like this:

```
If [State]="NSW" Then
    For Each Record In    tblCustomer
          Where Condition   =[State]="NSW"
          Alias             NSWCust
        EditRecord
              Alias         NSWCust
            SetField
                  Name    MyobID
                  Value   = "02-" & Right([MyobID],5)
        End EditRecord
End If
```

When I call it from the other macro, using `RunDataMacro` it gives me error 3709.

Is this a bad way to go about fixing this? What's wrong with my execution?

Comment: I don't know why you're trying to use a data macro. What you should use is an update query.

Comment: The reason is because I've never done one before, whereas shifting over from excel, I'm used to making macros (usually vba) do all the mass work for me.

In hindsight that is exactly what I should have done. And what I have now done. Feel like wording that as an answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data macros are intended to be used as "triggers" (perform an action when a specific event occurs.
In order to update data, you should use an update query.
Statement would look like this:

```
UPDATE tblCustomer
SET MyobID = "02-" & Right([MyobID],5)
WHERE [State] = "NSW"
```